# Umbraco - Make ActionResult method react for certain Template

Tags: c#, umbraco

Imagine I have a `PageController`...

It supports the `DocumentType` `Page`:

```
public class PageController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    // Default method for DocumentType "Page"
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return View("~/Views/MVC/Page/Page.cshtml");
    }

    // Default method for DocumentType "Page", with "HomePage" Template
    public ActionResult HomePage(RenderModel model)
    {
        return View("~/Views/MVC/Page/Home.cshtml");
    }
}
```

You can see one of my Controller methods are called "HomePage". This is actually the name of a `Template` type assigned to `DocumentType` `Page`.

I'd like to call the Controller method: *BibblyWobble*, because it makes me laugh...

Is there an attribute to allow that method to react to a certain `Template`

It might look like this:

```
public class PageController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    ...

    [ForUmbracoTemplate("HomePage")]
    public ActionResult BibblyWobbble(RenderModel model)
    {...}
}
```

Comment: ActionResult or Controller Action? You are using different terminologies to represent MVC artifacts and I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.

Comment: An ActionResult refers to the method on the controller that returns an ActionResult... Yes, you can call them Controller methods/actions. Hope that helps :D - I've reworded my question slightly :)

Comment: @PatrickHuber - https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers ... see routing via template

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I decompiled the code from Umbraco 7.3 and it appears that you can add a template alias of "BibblyWobbble" to the Home Page Template and it will be resolved. The RouteDefinition class is used by the RenderRouteHandler.GetUmbracoRouteDefinition method when creating the controller. About half way down in the method, if the content has a template it will the Action of the RouteDefinition to the template alias. 

here is the page on template alias https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Design/Templates/

Comment: Why do you want to call BiblyWobble what do you want it to return?